# What is the IIS Express icon meant to be?

Tags: user-interface, icons, iis-express, system-tray

Using IIS Express as my development server in Visual Studio 2012, I notice a rather odd-looking silvery-blue icon appear in my system tray.  It turns out this is the IIS Express icon, as shown the the following image (the IIS Express icon is on the left):

[image: IIS Express icon shown on the left]

What is this icon supposed to represent?  For about a week I thought it was a stylised S, now it looks more like a tin can being crushed by a robot hand.

Comment: And the technical problem is that you cannot guess the meaning of that icon, right?

Comment: Let me [enlarge this icon](http://cgeers.com/2011/04/30/iis-express/) for you. Does it look more like stack of boxes now?

Comment: Great stuff, sir.  The smaller version of the icon really doesn't look like a stack of boxes, but I can certainly see them in the larger version.  If you add that comment as an answer, I'll mark it quick before someone closes this question :P

Comment: While I appreciate this topic wholly, I find it a bit... too amusing for SO mods to handle. )

Comment: I thought it was a number 3!  I can never seem to find it when I'm looking for it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The icon illustrates a stack of blue blocks with the words:

> "INTEGRATED TOOL"
>  "DATABASE ENGINE"
>  "FRAMEWORK WEB APPS"
> "WEB SERVER"

Icon in a higher resolution:
[IIS Express Icon](https://ppolyzos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/iis-express-stack.png)

I found it on [this](https://ppolyzos.com/2015/12/01/enable-x64-bit-version-of-iis-express/) website.

Answer (score -1):

The icon you mention is the IIS Express System Tray application icon.

If you were to debug or run a Web Site or Web Application from the Visual Studio IDE, this icon will be displayed in your System Tray; you can right-click this icon and gain access to further features to stop these web sites and more.

IIS Express is somewhat similar to the Visual Studio Web Server in that it runs the web site/application under a random port on localhost. IIS Express is beneficial to use because incorporates the main Windows IIS Features without the need of requiring the Windows IIS Feature to be installed on the developer's computer; most corporates don't like to have the Windows IIS Feature installed because it represents a security risk to the company and requires more corporate management.

### References

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express